# Background misbehaving in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm making a modest portfolio and everything goes well but when I access the website from mobile browser (all of them) and scroll down the sections the backgrounds seems to be constantly resizing. This behaviour won't happen in desktop nor desktop browsers inspector. I tested it in mobile with google chrome, opera and firefox with the same result. I provide a screenshot showing the glitch:

[image]

I have a background placed in the body tag, and over it a class puts a translucid blue background. I think this might be it but I don't know for sure. Some code that might be relevant since the whole code is too long:

Background placed in body:

```
* {
    padding   : 0;
    margin    : 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size      : 10px;
    overflow-x     : hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-size      : 10px;
}

body {
    background-image     : $background-img;
    background-size      : cover;
    background-position  : center;
    background-repeat    : no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    min-height           : 100vh;
    height               : auto;
}
```

Every section puts another layer over it:

```
    .section {
        width          : auto;
        height         : auto;
        min-height     : 100vh;
        display        : flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items    : center;
        color          : white;
        background-color: #17223bc9;
    }
```

Here's the site: https://cromadev.com

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Viewport units don't work well on mobile browsers since the address bar/overall GUI of many mobile browsers resize as you scroll down, hence changing the size of the window.

Percentage units are more widely supported, so mobile browsers might render them in a more reliable way. Based on the code you provided, you can try them out by adding the following styles to your CSS (remove the `vh` styles, too):

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

You might have to experiment with switching `height` and `min-height` to get everything fully working for your specific use case.

You could also take a look at this GitHub project which aims to help fix some of these issues: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill -- but I would recommend you try out the percentages first.

Comment: Hi! Thanks, tried to put everything with percentages and the result was the same, also tried the viewport-units-buggyfill along browserify and still no luck. Maybe the issue is not related with viewport units? It feels like the background is being pushed. Thanks again.